# ag-grid-angular not displaying data in a tabular format

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid-angular to display data in a tabular format but all the data gets cluttered into one column.

I am using raw data to populate the ag-grid.

[image]

My component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {AgGridModule} from 'ag-grid-angular/main';
import {GridOptions} from 'ag-grid';


@Component({
 selector: 'app-main',
 templateUrl: './main.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
gridOptions: GridOptions;
columnDefs= [
   {headerName: 'Pokemon', field: 'name'},
   {headerName: 'Type', field: 'type'},
   {headerName: 'Price', field: 'price'},

];
rowData = [
{name : 'Bulbasaur', type: 'plant', price: 1000},
{name : 'Bulbasaur', type: 'plant', price: 1000},
{name : 'Bulbasaur', type: 'plant', price: 1000},
{name : 'Bulbasaur', type: 'plant', price: 1000},
{name : 'Bulbasaur', type: 'plant', price: 1000},
{name : 'Bulbasaur', type: 'plant', price: 1000},
{name : 'Bulbasaur', type: 'plant', price: 1000},
{name : 'Bulbasaur', type: 'plant', price: 1000},
{name : 'Bulbasaur', type: 'plant', price: 1000},
{name : 'Bulbasaur', type: 'plant', price: 1000},
{name : 'Bulbasaur', type: 'plant', price: 1000}
];
constructor() {
this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
  rowCount: 10
};
}

ngOnInit() {
}

}
```

the rowData and colDefs are declared in the above code

My component.html code:

```
<h1>Grid example</h1>

<ag-grid-angular class = "ag-fresh"
            [rowData]="rowData"
            [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
             [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
            >
 </ag-grid-angular>
```

My app.module.ts file:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';
import {AgGridModule} from 'ag-grid-angular';


@NgModule({
 declarations: [
 AppComponent,
 MainComponent
],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
AgGridModule.withComponents(MainComponent)
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: looks to me you are missing some ag-grid related styling, since that doesn't look like ag-grid at all?

Comment: Was this the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following into styles  section of **.angular-cli.json**

```
"../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css",
"../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/theme-fresh.css",
```

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial on building an ag-Grid with Angular CLI (https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-angular-angularcli/#creating-a-angular-project-with-ag-grid) on the bottom, they tell you to put the style sheets for ag-Grid into the angular-cli.json file. Like ishabi described.

To complete the answer and not just post the link:
Add the following two lines to your **.angular-cli.json** file:

```
 "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css",
 "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css"
```

Change the second line according to the theme you are using.